# Recommend a web file sharing software please

Tags: file-sharing, web, groups

I'm looking for a web platform to put company files at. My requirements are:

- should be accessible via a browser
- should be open source
- must be installable (dropbox is a no-go)
- must have an option to put a access time limit on a file
- must perform garbage collection automatically after a file expires
- must be able to mark files as public or private
- an option to protect a file via a pin-code for users without accounts in the system would be nice to have

The problem is I don't even know what to search for - all my googling results in either complete groupware solutions or p2p file sharing software. If such a thing doesn't exist, please don't hestitate to say so, so I can crawl to a corner and cry myself to sleep.

TIA

Comment: why is DropBox a "no-go"?

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a customized content management system (cms).  There are a lot of open source cms systems. Try Open-upload

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for something like this for a while now with no luck.
Your best guess is a webdav platform, or (s)ftp.

I've gone the sftp way, with one folder available over ftp to external, non AD users, and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

[ZendTo](http://zend.to/) might be a good starting point, though I'm not 100% sure if it supports everything you need. I know from experience of the author's other software that he'll be very responsive to any useful feature requests.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the [Turnkey File Server Appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/fileserver) a while ago but didn't care for eXtplorer's interface.  It does make files available through the major protocols (SMB, FTP, and Web).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my recommendations, but these are more enterprise solutions than open source build it yourself.

**Accellion**
http://www.accellion.com/

Just boot up the VM and off you go.
http://www.accellion.com/sites/default/files/datasheets/Virtual_Appliance_datasheet_1210.pdf

**Aspera**
http://www.asperasoft.com

Aspera Faspex
http://www.asperasoft.com/en/products/server_software_1/aspera_faspex_server_6

Both of these solutions should meet your requirements except for being open source.